# Averaging an element in 3D list python

Tags: python

I have a 3D list such as -

```
[
[[ 'A', 'B', 4], [ 'A', 'B', 6], [ 'A', 'B', 5], [ 'A', 'B', 7]],
[[ 'C', 'D', 5], [ 'C', 'D', 3], [ 'C', 'D', 2]],
[[ 'E', 'F', 4], [ 'E', 'F', 7], [ 'E', 'F', 3], [ 'E', 'F', 9], [ 'E', 'F', 11]]
....
..
]
```

I need to calculate the average of `3rd element` of each `2D list` and add it as an element in the list itself.

Tried `itertools` and other techniques to crawl the list but failing to get the number of elements in each `2D list` for average calculation.

Expected output of the list -

```
[
[[ 'A', 'B', 4], [ 'A', 'B', 6], [ 'A', 'B', 5], [ 'A', 'B', 7], [ 'A', 'B', 5.5]],
[[ 'C', 'D', 5], [ 'C', 'D', 3], [ 'C', 'D', 2], [ 'C', 'D', 3.3]],
[[ 'E', 'F', 4], [ 'E', 'F', 7], [ 'E', 'F', 3], [ 'E', 'F', 9], [ 'E', 'F', 11], [ 'E', 'F', 6.8]]
....
..
]
```

I have tried -

```
for eachReading in list_final:
    avg = sum(eachReading[0], eachReading[len(list_final - 1)]) / len(list_final)
    eachReading.append(eachReading[0], eachReading[1], avg)
```

Comment: There are too many ways to approach this problem. The answers would just turn into a straw-poll for which one people liked. The best thing is to do some research on the topic yourself, find two or three, _analyze_ them, determine if they work for you or not, and _try them out_. Come to us when you have a specific question about something you have attempted to do and show us a [mcve] of it explaining what is wrong with it.

Comment: You can get the average of each sublist by looping over the main construct and using something like `sum(i[2] for i in sublist) / len(sublist)`

Comment: Hey Ashish - if you're getting downvoted, it's best to think about why people are doing it, rather than appealing to them to stop.

Comment: Got it @Josh :)

Comment: Sure, glad you got your answer! Every one of us has gotten stuck on something simple at some point :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`itertools` is definitely an overkill. Use a simple loop (sorry for the terrible variable names):

```
li = [
      [['A', 'B', 4], ['A', 'B', 6], ['A', 'B', 5], ['A', 'B', 7]],
      [['C', 'D', 5], ['C', 'D', 3], ['C', 'D', 2]],
      [['E', 'F', 4], ['E', 'F', 7], ['E', 'F', 3], ['E', 'F', 9], ['E', 'F', 11]]
     ]

for inner_list in li:
    avg = sum(inner_inner[-1] for inner_inner in inner_list) / len(inner_list)
    inner_list.append([inner_list[0][0], inner_list[0][1], round(avg, 2)])  # round to
                                                                            # however many
                                                                            # digits you want

print(li)
```

Outputs

```
[[['A', 'B', 4], ['A', 'B', 6], ['A', 'B', 5], ['A', 'B', 7], ['A', 'B', 5.5]],
 [['C', 'D', 5], ['C', 'D', 3], ['C', 'D', 2], ['C', 'D', 3.33]],
 [['E', 'F', 4],
  ['E', 'F', 7],
  ['E', 'F', 3],
  ['E', 'F', 9],
  ['E', 'F', 11],
  ['E', 'F', 6.8]]]
```

Comment: Thanks @DeepSpace , I understand it was a waste question but at times it becomes difficult to gather exact solution for people who are new. I was hung up for long and finally asked. Never expected this, but really thanks anyway. It's works a charm!